# A finite bound on the Multi-dimensional tail sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say we have integers $m_1, m_2, \ldots m_n$ for a given $n = 2,3,4,\ldots$, and some positive integer $L$

I want to know if there's a finite bound on the tail sum
\begin{align}
\sum_{m_1 = L}^{\infty}\sum_{m_2 = L}^{\infty}\ldots\sum_{m_n = L}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{(m_1^2 + m_2^2 + \ldots + m_n^2)^2} \right] 
\end{align}
I'm interested in a bound that's a function of $n$ and $L$, and ideally, generalizes for all $n$.

I tried an integral bound on the sum $ \left(\int_{L}^{\infty}\ldots\int_{L}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\|x\|^4} \mathrm{d}x\right) $, but it holds only for $n \leq 4$, and gives $\infty$ for larger $n$. I was wondering if this bound even exists for all $n$, and if anyone could suggest resources (books/papers) on how to find it (or atlas show that it doesn't exist, if that's the case).